# Having trouble with wpapi, JSON, node.js

Tags: node.js, json, wordpress, syntax, wp-api

I want to retrieve content from my WordPress site through wpapi.  I've tried several endpoints and always get the same error, "Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0".  In the debugger, error.rawResponse looks good.  When I copy and paste the rawResponse into the VS Code editor, I can see an unprintable character before the legit JSON content starts.  Clearly this single character is the culprit.  Can anyone explain why this single character is present?

This is the code I'm trying to execute (with ids, pwds removed):

```
var WPAPI = require("wpapi");

var wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'http://example.com/wp-json',
    username: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    auth: true
});

wp.users()

    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.id);
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);

    });
```

Comment: I think the problem is extra space appearing at the response retrieved from page. Check whether the response you are catching up comes on json format. put some header like content-type.

Comment: I tried adding content-type header application/json but the behavior was unchanged.

Comment: Just for grins, I pointed my code a different Wordpress site.  The method returned without error!  Time to call my hosting provider.

Comment: One more piece of info: On Tools -> Site Health, I get an alert saying "The REST API did not behave correctly" with the detail message saying, The REST API did not process the context query parameter correctly."